# npm build fails at webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I honestly dont even know what question I should be asking here, but npm run build fails

```
> color-organizer@1.0.0 build /home/francis/Desktop/react/chapter-
06/color-organizer
> webpack --progress

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'set-blocking'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/francis/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/yargs/lib/usage.js:5:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

node -v gives me

```
v6.11.0
```

so its weird that i see 5 in this error log. I do need to note that i was running on 5 before, and just recently upgraded to 6.11 in the middle of this problem

i'm on ubuntu 16.04

i'm just trying to follow these examples https://github.com/MoonHighway/learning-react/ and start a server for 6, but i can't

and its pissing me off

Comment: Did you make sure the module `set-blocking` is installed?

Comment: To build on @Skam's comment, have you run `npm install`? (as described in the README: https://github.com/MoonHighway/learning-react/tree/master/chapter-06/color-organizer)

Comment: Regarding that you've changed the version in the middle of the problem, it is better ro remove all your `node_modules` then reinstalling them with `npm i` as it can cause some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm install` fixed the error for me using the latest versions. Otherwise you may try the command `npm install set-blocking` or `npm install set-blocking --save-dev` to only install the module as a developer dependency.